# Testing PayPal IPN SHA-256 Compliance with IPN Simulator

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I use the PayPal IPN for payment notification.
PayPal says all Https connections must be SHA-256 compliant by Sept 30, 2016. (ie Https using TLS 2.1)
In fact PayPal live testing begins on 6/17. A PayPal email stated *"We strongly recommend that your systems are compatible with SHA-256 by 17 June to ensure that your business isn’t interrupted."*

So I made a mod to my IPN webapp and tested it with the "PayPal IPN Simulator".
Resulting message = "IPN was sent and the handshake was verified."

Does anyone know if the "PayPal IPN Simulator" is Positive Confirmation that the IPN webapp is now SHA-256 compliant?

Update:
Here is the .Net HTTPS post-back code from my IPN app.

```
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls; 
    HttpWebRequest req =   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPN simulator won't confirm whether your script has done a post-back or not, the "*IPN was sent and the handshake was verified*" message only indicates an one-way connection success (from PayPal to your URL).

To ensure your web server is SHA-2 compatible when your IPN makes post-backs to PayPal, you may simply test the connection from your host to PayPal endpoints with command below (e.g. LAMP environment):

```
openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 -showcerts
```

or check the server trust store and see if G5 root cert is included,

```
ls -la /etc/ssl/certs/ | grep G5
```

Comment: pp_pduan thanks. My website resides on a shared Windows hosting server. I have asked their support team to confirm that the 'VeriSign G5 Root Certificate (SHA-256)' is in the certificate store. I hope that when the app post-back connects to PayPal it will use the G5 Root Certificate. I'm not a security pro so I have no idea how certificate selection is done when the app performs the post-back.

Comment: As long as the root cert is in your trust key store, it will be just fine. Cert selection is automated by server negotiation and a set of SSL handshake process